# Can we support oEmbed?

Tags: feature-request, third-party

From the [oEmbed](http://oembed.com/) site:

> oEmbed is a format for allowing an embedded representation of a URL on
>   third party sites. The simple API allows a website to display embedded
>   content (such as photos or videos) when a user posts a link to that
>   resource, without having to parse the resource directly.

This would be great for third-party sites to embed questions. Here's how it could work:

Stack Overflow creates an oEmbed endpoint that takes a URL-encoded URL as a parameter. Any site that wants to embed a URL will call it like this:

Format:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/oembed.{format}?url={url}
```

Example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/oembed.json?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2193953%2Fflash-cs4-refuses-to-let-go
```

It would then reply with a representation of that URL that can be embedded nicely:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "type": "link",
    "width": 300,
    "height": 100,
    "title": "Flash CS4 refuses to let go",
    "url": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193953/flash-cs4-refuses-to-let-go",
    "author_name": "Ender",
    "author_url": "http://stackoverflow.com/users/134658/ender",
    "provider_name": "Stack Overflow",
    "provider_url": "http://stackoverflow.com/"
    "html": "<html code that will display the question / answer embedded will be here>"
}
```

Additionally, it could be adjusted to return rich HTML, which would be nice if we wanted to include the score, or the user's avatar or something. That can be done with a type of 'rich'.

The oEmbed should also be discoverable, by adding a link tag to the document:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="stackoverflow.com/oembed.json?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2193953%2Fflash-cs4-refuses-to-let-go" title="Flash CS4 Refuses to Let Go" />
```

There are quite a few sites that already support oEmbed with great success such as YouTube, Flickr, Vimeo, Slideshare and WordPress. Here's an example of an oEmbed response from YouTube (that is easily taken from their autodiscovery  tag.)

- [YouTube oEmbed Example](http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DJ---aiyznGQ&format=json)
- [Speaker Deck oEmbed Example](https://speakerdeck.com/oembed.json?url=https://speakerdeck.com/u/mauris/p/rapid-api-development-with-packfire-framework&format=json)

Comment: Could go the other way for one boxing in chat if this isn't already used for that.

Comment: Please also make it have JSONP handling like a lot of other oEmbed endpoints do. It makes it easier for client only applications.

I also write a library that does a stack overflow embedding see https://github.com/starfishmod/jquery-oembed-all this may help in the meantime?

Comment: Author name should be [Ender](http://stackoverflow.com/users/134658/ender)

Comment: Seems like a bit of an XSS nightmare with the scrubbing necessary for every oEmbed being displayed...

Comment: @ChrisS: …what?

Comment: As an aside: YouTube (nowadays) returns an iframe (plus the meta data). The Speaker Deck example doesn't work for me today.

Comment: @ChrisS This is not about embedding things from other sites within Stack Exchange posts, it's about StackExchange providing an API to let other sites embed our questions - the same way you can embed a youtube video on a third party site.